# Getting variable from array then pass to url on nodejs request module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this array and need to pass all the variables inside the request url.
I've tried as result.variable1, result['variable1'], result[0], but nothing works.

How can access each variable inside the array and pass to url?

```
result.push({variable1: string1, variable2: string2});
    
request.post({
  url: "mydomain.com/text="Hi"+result[variable1]+"\\n"+result[variable2]+"Hello!",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': 'application/json'                              
  },
  rejectUnauthorized: false,//add when working with https sites
  requestCert: false,//add when working with https sites
  agent: false,//add when working with https sites
  form: {
    myfield: "myfieldvalue"
  }
}, function (response, err, body){
  console.log('Body:',JSON.parse(body));
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Your quoting in the `url:` property is all messed up. If you want to use `"` inside the string, use `'` as the delimiters around the string.

Comment: But I'm not sure why you think you need quotes in the URL parameters. It should just be `text=Hi` rather than `text="Hi"`

Comment: You should also use `encodeURIComponent` to ensure that the parameters are encoded properly.

Comment: You've pushed it as object. Now you need to you index to reference that object  like result[0] then you dot to get property of that object as result[0].variable1 and so on ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result.push({variable1: string1, variable2: string2});` 
This will result in the array becoming as 
`result = [{variable1: string1, variable2: string2}]`. 
So if you want 'variable1', you need to access it as `result[0].variable1`.